# Copy/Paste Excel cells to Word in loop not working/saving properly

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Admittedly new to VBA. I have an excel file that consists of all our part numbers broken down by "-" marks that I wrote code to break down into more descriptive phrases for making labels. I am trying to write code here to loop through different types of part numbers, grab particular cells in that part #'s row and copy/pasting them into a word document and saving the word doc as the part #'s name. As is, it loops but grabs all the info from the different ranges instead of just the info from the same row as part.

The code works (besides saving) if I change the ranges to 1 single cell, but once I have multiple cells in the ranges, it begins copying everything in the range instead of just in the row of the part that it should be looping.

```
Sub exceltoword2()

Dim part As Range
Dim funct As Range
Dim finish As Range
Dim lever As Range
Dim backset As Range
Dim trim As Range

Set part = Range("A2:A5")
Set funct = Range("Q2:Q5")
Set finish = Range("R2:R5")
Set lever = Range("S2:S5")
Set backset = Range("T2:T5")
Set trim = Range("U2:U5")

Dim wdapp As Word.Application
Set wdapp = New Word.Application
Dim SaveName As String

Dim path As String
path = "C:\Users\bpickett\Desktop\Parts\"

For Each part In part 'Long list of part #'s that will be looped through with particular variables commented out as needed as I adjust range on part variable

     With wdapp
    .Visible = True
    .Documents.Add
    .Activate

    part.Copy '********************************Part copied
    .Selection.PasteSpecial
        With .Selection '**********************Function copied
            .Font.Name = "Calibri"
            .Font.Size = 22
            .TypeText "FUNCTION       " '7 spaces
        End With
    funct.Copy
    .Selection.PasteSpecial
    With .Selection '**************************Finish
            .Font.Name = "Calibri"
            .Font.Size = 22
            .TypeText "FINISH              " '14 spaces
        End With
    finish.Copy
    .Selection.PasteSpecial
    With .Selection '***************************Backset
            .Font.Name = "Calibri"
            .Font.Size = 22
            .TypeText "BACKSET          " '10 spaces
        End With
    backset.Copy
    .Selection.PasteSpecial
   ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 path & part & ".docx"
End With
Next
End Sub
```

The code when ran has the 1st part # correct then, just copies the entire range of Backset/Function/Finish under each instead of just the single cell in the row of the part #.

Comment: A few notes of quick feedback:  **1)** you should fully-qualify your ranges,**2)**  `For Each part In part` doesn't make sense; maybe `For Each c In part` where `c` is each cell in the range you set as `part`, and **3)** you are trying to add and `.activate` each doc in Word, when you should be setting a new document as a variable and utilizing said variable (think `with-statement`).

Comment: Another, very important observation: As it stands, this question is "too broad" - you're asking too many things. You might want to review the site's guidelines in the [help], but one of the rules is: ONE issue per question. You need to break this down to ONE issue. You can use the [edit] link to change the content to present and ask one question (and remove information not relevant to it, so that it's easier for us to process). For additional problems, ask a new question, please.

Comment: As I see it, excel is doing what you ask it to do. When you say 'for each part in part', excel is looping through each cell in the 'part' range. Within that loop you ask excel to copy and paste the other defined ranges. If you want to copy and paste the specific row for the part number, you need to tell it that.

If I make the assumption this is a one off task and efficiency is not important, I would think the easiest solution would be to use 'offset' ie use part.offset(0,N).copy (where N is the column offset from the part #).

Answer (score 0):

Took advice from comments above and did a days more worth of research and made some changes that solved all problems.

```
For i = 1 to 1275
Set part = Range("A" & i)
Set funct = Range("Q" & i)
Set finish = Range("R" & i)
Set lever = Range("S" & i)
Set backset = Range("T" & i)
Set trim = Range("U" & i)
```

Qualifying the ranges(or at least to me it did) and adding the i array instead of for each part in part was huge for code to loop and grab only necessary information. But when running, it was crashing with error 4605 a lot. But a 7 year old question that was answered on here surrounded the copy/paste commands with labels and error handler

```
Pg1CopyAttempt:
DoEvents
part.Copy
On Error GoTo Pg1PasteFail
.selection.pastespecial
On Error goto 0 'disable the error handler

Pg1PasteFail:
If Err.Number = 4605 Then ' clipboard is empty or not valid.
    DoEvents
    Resume Pg1CopyAttempt
 End If
```

Which worked FLAWLESSLY to go through strings of 100's or 1000's of loops(Files created). Just had to modify Pg1 to 2 to 3 and ect through code.